# DS213air NAS keeps disconnecting

Tags: connection, nas, synology

*(Frustration level 10)*

I have a Synology DS213air connected via Ethernet and a switch to my Windows 7 PC. Wireless is switched off (that's an other problem).

Synology Assistant never has any problem finding the NAS:

[image]

On rare occasions I can map the drive to Windows' file system, but already after a couple of minutes I get the error:

[image]

Synology Assistant still finds the NAS.
Now, when I try to re-map the drive, after half a minute or so of "Connecting to server" I get the error message "The network path was not found".

[image]

[image]

Sometimes mapping succeeds after half a dozen tries, sometimes it doesn't work at all, not even after restarting the NAS and restarting the PC.

The DS213air is very versatile, which is the reason why I don't find configuring it straightforward. Any pointers to a possible cause for the continuous disconnecting and a cure are greatly appreciated.

PS: I can't remove the switch, because I also use it for my connection to the Internet.

---

**update**
Mapping in Windows Explorer instead of Synology Assistant doesn't seem to make any difference. There's a slight improvement when I use a static IP address: when I click a NAS folder in Windows Explorer there's no response for more than 2 minutes(!), but then I get to see the folder's files.

In Directory Opus (an Explorer replacement) there's a shorter pause (still about 1 minute), and then I get this error:

[image]

but oddly enough after that the folders and files are accessible.

Comment: First, set your NAS to a static IP address, DHCP for this kind of device is not very applicable. Does this also happen when you map the drive with Windows Explorer and not with "Synology Assistant"? Is there any chance to get some logfiles from this device?

Comment: @stevenvh: How are you mapping the drive, have you tried using the IP address? Also, have you tried a different Ethernet cable?

Comment: No need to blur your private IPs. Could have done the SN though if you wanted to be tinfoil hat. Grab putty and SSH to the synology(load of guides) then see if theres a crash when you lose access.

Comment: This is a software fault on the NAS. Are there any updates available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing the switch by a router, so that I can use a local 192.168.x.x IP address.